# UPDATE All time fields

Tags: mysql

I'm programming a website in PHP and I have a database table where there's events happening by time range

```
Field 1 : event_start
Field 2 : event_end
Field 3 : event_queue
```

event_queue is a delay 20 seconds between the next event_start time and previous event_end time, each event takes 1 minute.
For example:

```
event_start : 2016-02-10 04:00:00
event_end : 2016-02-10 04:01:00
event_queue : 2016-02-10 04:01:20
```

Next Event is

```
event_start : 2016-02-10 04:01:21
event_end : 2016-02-10 04:02:21
event_queue : 2016-02-10 04:02:41
```

Next Event is

```
event_start : 2016-02-10 04:02:42
event_end : 2016-02-10 04:03:42
event_queue : 2016-02-10 04:04:01
```

I don't know how to make an update query for such a task. And sorry for not providing any code but I'm sure I've fully described the issue